# Ckeditor not saving button tag

Tags: php, ckeditor

When I enter save html through ckeditor I miss  tag from the html content. Is there any ckeditor configuration I have to do to allow html tags such as  inside html content? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the allowedContent property when instantiating ckeditor to allow specific tags, or **allowedContent: true** to allow everything

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-allowedContent

Either using config.js, or in-page configuration for the specified textarea:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_configuration.html

In my case (I am using a Symfony ckeditor bundle) I also can set it via bundle configuration inside config.yml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.